# writting first $4$ terms and estimate of limit of $\{S_{n}\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> We have Given $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3}{10^k}.$
>
> $(a)$ Writting the first $4$ terms of sequence of partial sum
>
> $(b)$ Estimate the limit of $\{S_{n}\}$ or state that it does not exists.

What i try

For part $(a)$

$$\frac{3}{10}+\frac{3}{10^2}+\frac{3}{10^3}+\frac{3}{10^4}$$

But i did not understand the meaning of part $(b)$ can someone please explain me. Thanks

Comment: Note the sum is that of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: Thanks John Omielan. I have a little doubt in part $(a)$ can i write only $4$ terms or we also calculate these $4$ terms sum

Comment: Note the part (a) question actually asks you to write the $4$ terms of "sequence of partial sum". As such, it wants you to determine the specific values of $\frac{3}{10}$, $\frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{10^2}$, $\frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{10^2} + \frac{3}{10^3}$, and $\frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{10^2} + \frac{3}{10^3} + \frac{3}{10^4}$. Then part (b) wants you to look at how these partial sums are changing to either estimate what you think the limiting value will be as the number of terms goes to infinity (but note, you you can actually also determine this sum exactly) or state it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$\frac{3}{10}+\frac{3}{10^2}+\frac{3}{10^3}+\frac{3}{10^4}=0,3333.$$

Furthermore

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3}{10^k}= \frac{3}{10}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}(\frac{1}{10})^k.$$

Geometric series !

Hence

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{3}{10^k}=0, \overline{3}= \frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here
 $ S_n = \frac {3}{10} + \frac {3}{10^2} +...+ \frac {3}{10^n}=\frac {3}{10}[\frac {1-\frac{1}{10^n}}{1-\frac {1}{10}}]
=\frac {3}{10}\frac {10}{9}[1-\frac {1}{10^n}]$
And clearly $ S_n \rightarrow \frac {1}{3}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$